# How can I detect click on a UI button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am making a piano game/app in unity and I want to be able to record the players notes and then play it back, I found a way to do that with an ArrayList, but I activate recording by a KeyPress, I want to do it by clicking a UI Button in unity. I can't figure out how to do that. The other problem I have is that the game doesn't play the notes after it records, I want to be able to play the notes while I am recording and also if I am not recording. My Code is down below, thank you for any help

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NotePlay: MonoBehaviour
{


    Button record;
    public bool recordMode = false;
    Animator anim;
    public AudioClip noteA;
    public AudioClip noteB;
    public AudioClip noteC;
    public AudioClip noteD;
    public AudioClip noteE;
    public AudioClip noteF;
    public AudioClip noteG;
    public AudioSource audio;

    // Use this for initialization

    public ArrayList notes;

    void Start()
    {
        anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
        audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        notes = new ArrayList();

    }

    void Playback()
    {
        print(notes.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < notes.Count; i++)
        {

            char c = (char)notes[i];
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            PlayNote(c);

        }


    }

    void PlayNote(char note)
    {

        if (note == 'a')
        {

            //anim.SetTrigger("A");
            GameObject.Find("Sphere_A").GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(noteA);
            GameObject.Find("Sphere_A").GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("A");

        }
        if (note == 'b')
        {

            //anim.SetTrigger("B");
            GameObject.Find("Sphere_B").GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(noteB);
            GameObject.Find("Sphere_B").GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("B");
            print("b");

        }
        if (note == 'c')
        {

            ///anim.SetTrigger("C");
            GameObject.Find("Sphere_C").GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(noteC);

        }
        if (note == 'd')
        {

            //anim.SetTrigger("D");
            GameObject.Find("Sphere_D").GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(noteD);

        }
        if (note == 'e')
        {

            //anim.SetTrigger("E");
            GameObject.Find("Sphere_E").GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(noteE);

        }
        else if (note == 'f')
        {

            // anim.SetTrigger("F");
            GameObject.Find("Sphere_F").GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(noteF);

        }
        else if (note == 'g')
        {

            //anim.SetTrigger("G");
            GameObject.Find("Sphere_G").GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(noteG);

        }


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {

            recordMode = !recordMode;


        }

        if (recordMode == true)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) { notes.Add('a'); print("a"); }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B)) {notes.Add('b'); print("b"); }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C)) notes.Add('c');
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)) notes.Add('d');
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) notes.Add('e');
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F)) notes.Add('f');
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G)) notes.Add('g');


        }
        else
        {

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
            {

                Playback();

            }
        }

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, you need to add a listener to your button. Add this to your `Start()` method:

```
record.OnClick.AddListener(()=>{ recordMode = !recordMode; });
```

This will make it so that when the button attached to the `record` field is pressed, the action is executed.

For the second part of your question you could call `PlayNote()` every time the note is recorded like so:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G)){
 notes.Add('g');
 PlayNote('g');
}
```